# Finding a plane that contains $L_1$ but does not intersect $L_2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given two lines

$L_1: x=1+2t,\ y=3t,\ z=2-t$

$L_2: x=-1+s,\ y=4+s,\ z=1+3s$

find an equation for a plane that contains $L_1$ but does not intersect $L_2$

Comment: Hint:  Since the plane does not intersect $L_2$ it is parallel to it.  Hence its normal vector is orthogonal to both L1 and L2 and passes through any point on $L_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what the question is asking for here, we want our plane to **contain** $L_1$ and **never intersect** $L_2$. So we have two information to decipher.

First up, in order for a plane to contain a line, the plane must be *parallel* to it and also share a common point. This is somewhat like if two lines are parallel and share a common point then they coincide, except here the plane spans infinite lines.

Recall the vector representation of a plane, that is
\begin{equation}
P:\vec{u}=\vec{a}+\lambda\vec{m}+\mu\vec{p}
\end{equation}
Where $\vec{m},\vec{p}$ are any two lines parallel to, and $\vec{a}$ a point on the plane. From the discussion above we can see $L_1$ contains two of the information here.

Now for the second part. If you imagine it in your head, a line and a plane almost always intersect in $\mathbb{R}^3$, except when they're parallel. So $L_2$ has to be parallel to the plane but doesn't share a common point (otherwise it would be contained). This provides us with the last bit of information we need to uniquely define our plane.

[Here's an illustration of the relationship between the plane and the lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppUby.png)

We can also find the Cartesian equation using these information and the **point-normal form**, simply find the normal $\vec{n}$ using cross product and throw them into the formula.

Comment: The answer is good.  What's problematic, and the reason I can't give this an upvote, is that the original post showed absolutely no effort to reach an independent solution.  That's the kind of question we try to discourage here.

Comment: @RobertShore Now that you said it, this is conspicuously a homework question, do you think if it's better for me to take down the details of the solution and only leave hints? I'm new to this community

Comment: Yes, in my opinion that would be appropriate.  It's a shame, too, because this is a very good presentation of the answer.